# Caffe Layer function is not invoked

Tags: c++, neural-network, caffe, layer

I have written a custom layer in caffe (C++). While running this code (training a model which uses this layer), the setup layer (`"LayerSetUp"` method of the layer) gets called (verified by writing a piece of code which would create a file on hard disk and dump some data). But the `Forward_cpu()` and `Backward_cpu()` method don't seem to be called during execution. What could be the possible reason ?

Here's the output from running a model to train which uses this custom loss layer.

```
...
I0715 09:23:57.415463 31256 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer loss
I0715 09:23:57.415472 31256 net.cpp:406] loss <- permute_conv11
I0715 09:23:57.415482 31256 net.cpp:406] loss <- bbox
I0715 09:23:57.415495 31256 net.cpp:380] loss -> loss
I0715 09:23:57.433014 31256 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
I0715 09:23:57.437386 31256 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
I0715 09:23:57.438171 31256 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
I0715 09:23:57.438897 31256 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
I0715 09:23:57.438989 31256 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
I0715 09:23:57.440030 31256 net.cpp:122] Setting up loss
I0715 09:23:57.440052 31256 net.cpp:129] Top shape: (1)
I0715 09:23:57.440058 31256 net.cpp:132]     with loss weight 1
I0715 09:23:57.440099 31256 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 3146726596
...
```

The reason why the loss layer is invoked multiple times (in the above snippet) is, I used layers within my custom layer to invoke other layers, (softmax of type `"Softmax"`, sigmoid of type `"Sigmoid"`, reshape_softmax of type `"Reshape"`, reshape_sigmoid "Reshape" and another `"Reshape"` layer. All of these 5 layers act on different parts of the input blob to this custom layer)

Forward_cpu() method doesn't seem to be invoked at all while training the model. What could be the problem and how do I resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that `Forward_gpu()` method is invoked in this case. To overcome this error make sure that you don't have `<your_custom_layer>.cu` file which implements `Forward_gpu` and `Backward_gpu()`

Comment: Yes, that was the issue ! Thanks a lot